# Issues with using multiple * in the grep command

Tags: grep, find

Does anyone know why using two *'s in a grep command will not return anything. My original command is as follows:

```
find | grep 0000\:00\:*.0/usb1/authorized_default
```

In this example, I am attempting to return a file that I do not know the PCI folder name. This command works perfectly and as expected(taking the * as a wildcard) and figuring out that usb1 is in the '1a' folder.

Why does grep not return any results if I place another wildcard in the command to replace 'usb1' with 'usb*'? My end goal is to return all of the authorized_default files which I realize can be done other ways and probably more efficiently. My question then becomes not how can I do this but why does grep not return a result when I put another '*' symbol into the equation?

```
find | grep 0000\:00\:*.0/usb*/authorized_default
```

Thanks in advance for your time and responses.

Answer (score 6):

`grep` uses [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Examples), not [shell globs](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob).

The regex `0000:00:*.0/usb1/authorized_default` matches the string `0000:00` + zero or more colons + any character + `0/usb1/authorized_default`.

If you swap the `*` and the `.`, it will match any string that contains `0000:00` followed by  `0/usb1/authorized_default`. (`.*` matches any number (`*`) of any character (`.`).)

Similarly, `usb*/` will match `us/`, `usb/`, `usbbb/` etc, but not `usb1`.

---

Actually, there's also the issue that the unquoted `*` in the argument to `grep` is taken as a glob character *by the shell*, before `grep` even sees it. So, if there are files that would match `0000\:00\:*.0/usb*/authorized_default` as a glob pattern, that would affect the string that goes to `grep`. Multiple matches would go as multiple arguments, and `grep` would take the ones after the first as filenames.

Put quotes around any regular expressions on the command line to prevent that.

---

In any case, you don't even need the `grep` here, as @Kusalananda says. The  `-name` option to `find` can be used to match filenames against a glob pattern. At least some `find` implementations also have the `-regex` option to match file names against regular expressions.

---

There are also a number of variants of regular expressions, see: [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/119905/170373)

Answer (score 2):

As ilkkachu already pointed out, `grep` uses basic regular expressions, which means that `:*` matches zero or more `:`, and `b*` matches zero or more `b`.

---

Do not `grep` the output of `find`, instead use `find` to look for your file. In the general case, filenames may contain newlines, which would make grepping not work.  Using `find` to directly filter the pathnames that you want to see is also more efficient, and safer.

```
find . -type f -name 'authorized_default'
```

If you have to do matching on other parts of the pathname:

```
find . -type f -path '*0000:00:*.0/usb*/authorized_default'
```

`-path` works like `-name` but matches a filename globbing pattern against the whole path rather than just against the filename part of the pathname (a `*` may match across one or several `/`).

Related:

- [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697)